# How to write a failing test in this case?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea, junit, evosuite

I want to test some simple programs with evosuite in intellij and I want some test be failed . I was generated test with evosuite and  test_cases are built. But when i test them with junit after, all of them are passed!

How can I fail some test in program?
This is my simple program that I add "while(true)" to be wrong:

```
While(true) 
      int a=8;
      int b=2;
      a=b;
```

Answer (score 0):

use assertions, abort() method, and throw exceptions as needed.

imagine you have a method which is expected to return 2.
here is how you can test it:

```
int a = yourmethod();
Assert.assertEquals(2, a);
```

if a certain condition should be satisfied:

```
if (condition) {
// Check something else
} else {
abort() // this method fails the test
}
```

Comment: Actually i know so so little about test and evosuite. But i must do that and that is so emergency.....can you explain more please???? And edit my simple code for example.... Thank you so much

Comment: اگه فارسی توضیح بدید هم مشکلی نیس.هر جور راحت هستید

Comment: har koja az method e test age exception rokh bede un test fail mishe. ye rahe dg ke dar sharayeti ke mikhayn yek test ro fail konid ine ke az method e abort() estefade konid (masalan dakhele ye if ke age bargharar nabashe test bayad fail she). assertion ha ham sharayete dakhele yek test ro check mikonan va age bargharar nabashe uno fail mikonan. masalan assretEquals() do ta argument migire ke yekish javabie ke entezar darid va yekish javabie ke barname be shoma mide va age in 2 ta mosavi nabashan un test ro fail mikone.